# Erro no index e ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, lista

Este é meu código:

```
 public static ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.din);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.dequi);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.demer);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.debai);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.deval);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.denin);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.degoo);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.dehub);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.debqui);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.debmer);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.debbai);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.debval);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.debnin);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.debgoo);
 Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Add(Form2.Globals.debhub);

 StreamWriter save = new StreamWriter(savegame);
 {
      for (int i = 0; i < Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
      {
            save.WriteLine(Form2.Globals.listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
      }
      save.Dispose();
      save.Close();
 }

 var din2 = Globals.listBox1.Items[0]; // <- line error
 Globals.din = Convert.ToDouble(din2);
```

> Erro:
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value '0' não é um valor
>   válido para 'index'.

[Printscreen/Screenshot](https://snag.gy/SsYn0d.jpg).

Comment: Esse código é bem complicado e faz coisas que não deveriam, mas o problema é que deve faltar o `Form2` antes de `Globals.listBox1.Items` na linha do erro. É só o que vejo de diferente que poderia causar o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note que em todo o código está usando uma lista chamada `Form2.Globals.listBox1`, portanto essa variável `listBox1` está em `Form2.Globals`. Mas no momento que vai acessar a variável, o nome não está completo e aparentemente existe uma variável com mesmo nome principal existe em outro local, e aí esta variável não tem elementos nela. Na linha do erro está acessando `Globals.listBox1`. É diferente.

O código tem vários outros problemas que parece funcionar, mas está errado.